# How to calculate sum of values per column except one column to have total values per each column in PROC SQL / SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, sum, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table (with only numric columns) in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
YEAR   | COL1  | COL2
-------|-------|------
2021   | 20    | 10
2022   | 25    | 30
2023   | 5     | 1
```

And I need to sum values in each column except column "YEAR" to have total value per column. So I need something like below:

```
YEAR   | COL1  | COL2
-------|-------|------
2021   | 20    | 10
2022   | 25    | 30
2023   | 5     | 1
TOTAL  | 50    | 41
```

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide / PROC SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

So that looks like a REPORT and not a DATASET.  So use a reporting procedure.
Examples:

```
data have;
  input YEAR COL1 COL2;
cards;
2021 20  10
2022 25  30
2023 5   1
;

proc print data=have;
  id year ;
  sum col1 col2 ;
run;

proc report data=have;
  define year / order ;
  rbreak after / summarize;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only summed values you can make a new table:

```
data have;
    input year col1 col2;
    datalines;
2021 20 10
2022 25 30
2023 5 1
;
quit;



proc sql;
    create table want as
        select sum(col1) as total_col1, sum(col2) as total_col2
            from have
    ;
quit;
```

If you want it in original table (I have no idea why you would like that) you can do it by firstly creating a new table for totals, and adding it to your old table. But you won't be able to have 'TOTAL' in your YEAR column as it should be num type. So I just left YEAR as missing in that row. That second approach is like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select . as YEAR, sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2
            from have
    ;
quit;

data want2;
    set have want;
run;
```

Comment: Negdo, what If I have column whihc name is like "A BC" which white symbol between characters ? how can I such column in your code ?

Comment: The best way is to use an actual variable name for the variable and put the pretty description in the variable's LABEL where it belongs.  But if you insist on using strange names and have enabled their usage by setting the system option VALIDVARNAME=ANY then you have to use name literals to reference the variables in the code.  A name literal is a quoted string with the letter n right after the close quote.  `'A BC'n`